# TDD with database and Go

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to wrap my head around test driven development with Go and having an issue testing my CRUD functions since they are written for my production database.  I'm coming from Ruby on Rails so I am used to using a test database, but Go doesn't seem to be too friendly in this regard.

So, how does one go about testing CRUD with Go?

> main.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
)

type book struct {
    id     int     `json:"id"`
    isbn   string  `json:"isbn"`
    title  string  `json:"title"`
    author string  `json:"author"`
    price  float32 `json:"price"`
}

// type Books []*Book

// CRUD functions for Book
func (b *book) getBook(db *sql.DB) error {
    return db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=$1", b.id).Scan(&b)
}
```

> app.go

```
func (a *App) Initialize(dbname string) {
    var err error
    a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

> my test

```
func TestGetBook(t *testing.T) {
    clearTable()
    addBook(1)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/book/1", nil)
    response := executeRequest(req)
    checkResponseCode(t, http.StatusOK, response.Code)
}
```

The problem is that this keeps on looking at the `books` table in my DB, not the `books_test` table I'd like to use for testing.  How can I go about making ONLY the tests use the `books_test` DB?

Comment: TestFoo() just runs Foo() function. Hence when you run the test you run the query `SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=$1`, the go code doesn't even know about a table `book_test` in your database. I don't know any Ruby so may be what you're expecting is something specific to the Ruby language.

Comment: Could you have two databases instead? `bookstore` and `bookstore_test` ? And in your go code, you could probably initialize the connection based on your runtime environment if you're running in production or test. (like checking for an env variable?)?

Comment: Mock your database, for example using [testify's mock](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/README.md#mock-package). Unit tests should never run against a real database. That would make it hard to test the resilience of your code against failures and adds an extra system to your tests. Test against a real database in integration tests.

Comment: @hbagdi Yes, but if you do that, make sure you can and do regenerate bookstore_test as part of your test run. So you know it's in revision control.

Comment: I recommend you to use different databases, not different tables (or schemas)  in the same database. There's no sense to test your app with another database structure. Let your app to take db name from environment variables. Thus you'll achieve all goals: you have the same app and the same db structure. So we use db `project` as a main production db, and `project_test` as db for tests.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky yes, I agree with you, but how?  My development DB doesn't have SSL and if I attempt to create the connection with `db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=pqgotest dbname=pqgotest sslmode=disable")` I get an error that `SSL mode is not enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dev/test database which should be a complete copy of your production database. You will never want to run test directly against your production database since too many unexpected issues could happen.

A workaround would be starting up your app first, which creates the connection to your database, then run the test. You can use IntelliJ to achieve this.

TDD in my opinion is great for developing business logic layer code since new models and business processes can have unexpected impacts on existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

@Godzilla74, there'are 2 solutions: enable SSL for test DB (try to check database settings or ask your system administrator) of have completely different setting for test:

```
func (a *App) Initialize(dbname string) {
    var err error
    pgsettings := os.Getenv("PGSETTINGS")
    if pgsettins == "" {
      // default options if not overridden
      pgsettins := "postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore?sslmode=disable"  
    }
    a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", pgsettins)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

So you can run set environment setting to any required value and run app, like so:

```
export PGSETTINGS="postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore_test?sslmode=disable"  
go run main.go
```